# asdf message "No version set for command rails" when running Rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asdf-vm

I am trying to run my rails server (`rails s`) in my Rails 3.2.13 application after having updated my Ruby version in `/.ruby-version` and `/.tools-versions`, but get the following message:

```
asdf: No version set for command rails

you might want to add one of the following in your .tool-versions file:

ruby 2.2.4
```

However, I had updated ruby in both version files to 2.3.0 and it is reflected in both. When I type `asdf which ruby` the ruby version is also 2.3.0.

I'd like help understanding why `rails s` prompts this asdf message, and what I'm missing with how to fix it so that I can run the rails server.

Comment: The `asdf-ruby` plugin: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
asdf reshim ruby
```

Then run `rails s` again

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to also restart my shell

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me in such situation where reshim did not work.

```
gem update --system
```

Credits to https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/127#issuecomment-644399342